# lose 4 hours in conversion from UTC

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a script that requests a datapull from a sql server.

For the request I send string like:
`start_of_pull="2018-09-13 11:00:00"`
The sql script pulls the data using UTC timestamp.

It returns a UTC timestamp of 
`1536850800`.
But when I use pandas' `pandas.to_datetime(df['TIME'],unit='s')`
it returns at timestamp of
`2018-09-13 15:00:00`

Any ideas why I'm losing 4 hours?

My solution to the problem is to subtract 14,400 seconds

Comment: Is your server in a UTC+4 or UTC-4 time zone?

Comment: For people in North America Eastern time 15:00 UTC is 11:00 Daylight savings time. I know nothing about panda, but my guess is when you send your request the SQL server believes you are sending UTC, and then the panda_todatetime() method returns a timestamp correct for your timezone based on your environment. Look at the documentation for the method you use for sending the request, and see how you can specify the time zone. Same with to_datetime(). Wouldn't be surprised the SQL server assumes UTC unless you specify otherwise. Just speculation, but a place to start looking.

Comment: And as a general comment, when dealing with date/times you must always be conscious of time zones. Subtracting 14000 secs would solve your problem today, but then your code will fail again when we move the clocks forward or backward, of your code gets executed on a computer located in a different time zone.